# How to return list reults to current jsp in spring MVC by controller

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value="/doSearch", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView listSerchClients(@RequestParam("bnCustomerName") String searchText) {
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    model.put("sclients",  prepareListofBean(clientService.listSearchClientss(searchText))) ;            
    return new ModelAndView("serchResult", model);
}
```

Curently Searchresults return to `serchResult.jsp`  but i want to keep serch result in current jsp (search.jsp) how to achieve this

[view Search.jsp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOGxr.png)

Comment: what is view resolver config. please provide

Answer (score 1):

> Curently Searchresults return to `serchResult.jsp` but i want to keep serch result in current jsp (`search.jsp`) how to achieve this

This is because you return `serchResult.jsp` in the method. Just change the returning `ModelAndView` to `search`

```
return new ModelAndView("search", model);
```

Comment: i tried that way but no results instead of that  i used sechResult.jsp but my requerment is to get result to same page

Comment: is it possible to return object to same jsp ? what kind of changes must done for jsp?

Comment: you can put the data into the model and redirect to the page you want.

Comment: how can I always return to the page the user is currently on?